# Getting error in setting up Cocoa Pods and install update for Ruby

Tags: objective-c, ruby, macos, cocoa, cocoapods

I am trying to setup cocoapods to my iOS application But when I go for command:

```
sudo gem update --system
```

I get error : Latest version currently installed. Aborting.

When I go to next step for cocoapods:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

I get error on Mac OS 10.8.5 :

```
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
cocoapods-trunk requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0.
```

I tried same on Mac OS 10.9.4 and getting error :

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0), here is why:
      Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)​
```

Comment: When trying to install ruby and rvm, I am getting error : RVM sourcing line not found for Zsh, rerun this command with '--auto-dotfiles' flag to fix it. and warning : * WARNING: You have '~/.profile' file, you might want to load it,
    to do that add the following line to '/Users/sharmas7/.bash_profile':

      source ~/.profile and error for ruby: No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-2.0.0-p598

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had this same problem and found it was due to having an older version of Ruby installed (even though my OS X is 10.10.2).  You will need to uninstall the old version and install a newer version of Ruby.  These steps worked for me:

1. Try `rvm ls` to see if you have a newer version installed.  If you do, just use it with `rvm use ruby-2.2.0`, for example.
2. If you don't have an unused compatible version, uninstall the old version: `rvm uninstall [your ruby version]` (you may have to uninstall cocoapods first if this line gives you an error).  Use `rvm current` to see what version you're running.
3. Install version 2.2.0 (or use `rvm list known` to see all available versions; 
   2.2.0 worked for me, but 2.2-head did not): `rvm install ruby-2.2.0`
4. When it's done: `rvm --create ruby-2.2.0`, and then `rvm use ruby-2.2.0`
5. Reinstall cocoapods

Comment: the best guide I've seen to upgrading Ruby out there. Seriously

Comment: I followed these steps and uninstalled Ruby. Then tried to install 2.2 as per above and it needs something called homebrew. I found that and tried to install it, but it needs Ruby. I killed my chicken, and now I have no eggs :)

Comment: I guess you'd have to reinstall your old chicken.